# VB.NET - Reading a text file containing tab-separated integers/doubles and storing them in arrays

Tags: vb.net, text-files, streamreader

I have a text file containing tab-seperated integers and doubles, e.g.:

```
5[TAB]0.3[TAB]2.9[TAB]61[TAB]110
8[TAB]1.1[TAB]5.2[TAB]13[TAB]45
1[TAB]0.8[TAB]1.4[TAB]28[TAB]33
...
```

What I need is a convenient way to access each line as a double array in VB.NET - so that the first array would be [**5.0 0.3 2.9 61.0 110.0**], the second array would be [**8.0 1.1 5.2 13.0 45.0**], and so on...

How can this be accomplished using the StreamReader?

Comment: have you tried any approach, can i see your code for help?

Comment: @Sanfoor:  Yes, I've tried a bunch of things and I've also looked through most of the other posts dealing with reading text files from .NET. However, since I'm not much of a programmer, my attempts are pretty poor and not really helpful (IMO).
So far I've set up the stream reader, but as soon as it comes to chopping up the lines and storing the values (of each line) in double arrays, I'm pretty much lost. So any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's ok to use a list of lists instead of a list of arrays, you can just do this:

```
Private Function LoadFile(ByVal filePath As String) As List(Of List(Of Double))
    Dim records As New List(Of List(Of Double))()
    For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
        Dim values As New List(Of Double)()
        For Each field As String In line.Split(New String() {ControlChars.Tab}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            values.Add(Double.Parse(field))
        Next
        records.Add(values)
    Next
    Return records
End Function
```

Or, if it must be a list of arrays, you could do this:

```
Private Function LoadFileToArrays(ByVal filePath As String) As List(Of Double())
    Dim records As New List(Of Double())()
    For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
        Dim values As New List(Of Double)()
        For Each field As String In line.Split(New String() {ControlChars.Tab}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            values.Add(Double.Parse(field))
        Next
        records.Add(values.ToArray())
    Next
    Return records
End Function
```

If you need an array of arrays, you could just return `records.ToArray()`, instead, in that last example.  I did not add any code to handle invalid or empty field values, because it wasn't clear, in your question, how you would want to handle those.  So, you'll want to add code to handle that appropriately, otherwise, this code will throw an exception in such cases.

Comment: The second version (list of arrays) works almost perfectly for me!! Thank you so much for your help, Steven :D
There's only one tiny thing that needs to be resolved: When I use "LoadFileToArrays" to get one of the decimal values (e.g. 7.9 or 4.58) the decimal point is being removed, resulting in integers like 79 and 458. How to avoid that?

Comment: It works for me.  How are you viewing the values of the doubles?  Perhaps you are formatting it incorrectly.  If that's not the problem, perhaps your culture info is using a different character, such as a comma as the decimal separator character?

Comment: I just found out that this problem was indeed related to the decimal separator settings - I changed it from comma to period. Now it works ;) thanks for your help...