# How to read tab separated values and put them into List?

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file containing tab separated values that I would like to load into an array or list so that I can work with the values further. I have used the solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052508/vb-net-reading-a-text-file-containing-tab-separated-integers-doubles-and-stori) and I believe it is very close to what I need, however in my file the first value on each line is a date and time stamp, then each other value on that line will be a double.

For temporary testing I am attempting to load the values into a data grid view control, but I am getting an error that the input string was not in the correct format.
I will need to sort the values later by date/time so I definitely need to load those values in but I am unsure how to accomplish this?

```
Private Function LoadFile(ByVal filePath As String) As List(Of List(Of Double))

    'Look at a text file and load stored values into a list

    Dim records As New List(Of List(Of Double))()
    For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
        Dim values As New List(Of Double)()
        For Each field As String In line.Split(New String() {ControlChars.Tab}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            values.Add(Double.Parse(field))
        Next
        records.Add(values)
    Next

    Return records

End Function

Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click

    dgvValues.DataSource = LoadFile(strFullPath)

End Sub

Private Sub clbFileList_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles clbFileList.ItemCheck

    strFileName = clbFileList.SelectedItem.ToString
    strFullPath = strSourcePath + "\" + strFileName

End Sub
```

Here are a few lines as a sample from what I'm trying to read in to the program:

```
12:18:30 02-28-2014    189.233333333333    666.35

12:33:30 02-28-2014    274.716666666667    1111.35

12:48:30 02-28-2014    265.516666666667    1052.9

13:03:00 02-28-2014    253.583333333333    1164.25
```

Comment: you could define a class to hold the date, val1 and val2, then store them in a List(of MyClass)

Comment: Rather than implementing your own parsing system, you might want to look into the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) built into VB.

Comment: Thanks @JimWooley I am using the TextFieldParser and it's working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Class myStuff
   Public Property theDate As DateTime
   Public Property oneValue As Double         
   Public Property twoValue As Double

   ' optionally add a constructor to
   ' create the object with everything at once:
   Public Sub New(dt as DateTime, v1 As Double, v2 As Double)
       theDate = dt
       oneValue = v1
       twoValue = v2
   End Sub

End Class
```

Elsewhere:

```
Public stuffList As New List(Of MyStuff)


Dim El as MyStuff
' presumably in a loop:

' after you parse the text into date and doubles:
El = New MyStuff(dateRead, val1Read, val2Read)
stuffList.Add El
```

even more compact, with no temp Element var (above is more illustrative of the process):

```
stuffList.Add(New MyStuff(dateRead, val1Read, val2Read))
```

Comment: I am working to implement this to see if it works for me. I have one question though, would it be possible to integrate an optional header feature? Sometimes the files could include a header row.

Comment: yes, but the devil is in the details.  whats the relationship?  is there one header (string???) for a set of Date/Dbl/Dbl sets?  How is it used? You **could** add a string property to the class, but if there are different **sets** of these maybe a class wrapper for the List (or a Dictionary of Lists maybe).  More info needed, to be honest.

Comment: These files are generated by a device that logs data taken from sensors. Sometimes, there may be a header row, each header is specific to the column of data it is associated with, but it's just needs to be a string label. I do have to keep them together though. I was originally thinking I needed an array to hold all of this, but I was led into the list direction. I know how to do this kind of thing in RSLogix5000, just not VB :)

Comment: arrays are old school, Lists are much easier to work with.  you could add string properties to the class to store the strings.  since they are optional, I'd leave them out of the constructor and init them as `Property HeaderX As String = ""`, then set them only when detected.

Comment: @CanaanP  mark the answer as accepted if it helps, so others can find answers when (if) they search (gain yourself some rep too)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Plutonix but I'm using the TextFieldParser as advised by JimWooley and it's very simple.