# Reading integers from a text file only and separating

Tags: vb.net, listbox, integer, streamreader

I have created a program that successfully reads integers only from a text file that contains string as well into a listbox. For example:
The text file contains:

- Tyler 7
- Daniel 2
- Mike 6
- Rory 9

The listbox will then show: 7269.
However I plan to sort these numbers from highest to lowest (vice versa) and in order to do this I want to try store each number on a new line in the listbox but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.
The code I have used to read integers only is:

```
    Dim intOnly As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(File_1)

    Dim intValue As String = String.Empty

    For Each c As Char In intOnly

        If IsNumeric(c) Then

            intValue += c

        End If

    Next

    ListBox3.Items.Add(intValue)
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use strings for math!

Comment: Like : `If IsNumeric(c) Then ListBox3.Items.Add(c) ` ?

Comment: heh I am a bit of a novice but wouldn't string be better because it separates the integer from the string?

Comment: i guess if you want  to keep the numbers and don't wanna add them up thats ok for beginning

Comment: @Index that almost worked for what I was trying to do! The problem is though that it makes '10' show as '1' and '0' on separate lines, would there be a work around for this?

Comment: thats because you go throught your text char by char, so there is no way to tell were a number starts and were it ends. you should try to read your textfile line by line and then trimm the non Numeric chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub test()
    Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader("file.txt")
    Dim LofInt As New List(Of String)

    While sr.Peek <> -1
        Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine
        Dim intValue As String = String.Empty

        For Each c As Char In line
            If IsNumeric(c) Then
                intValue += c
            End If
        Next

        LofInt.Add(intValue)
    End While

    sr.Close()

    LofInt.Sort()
    For Each i In LofInt
        ListBox1.Items.Add(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

So basicly what we do:
We read you file line by line and store the numeric values. after each line we add what we've got to a list.
After that we use a function of that list to sort the "numers" (still a string, so we should say text) and add them to your listbox

Comment: As you can see in the answers below, there are more than one way to solve this. i've tried to keep near your approach as it might be easier to understand and may work for your program. When trying to filter numers from text - doing this char by char is the wrong way (in most cases). Even if you use this solution here - have a look at the other solutions and try to understand what they did.

Answer (score 0):

Making use of the `ListBox.DataSource` property and an array you would be able to display each number in a new line.

For eg:

```
aLstSrc = New Integer(2) {}
aLstSrc(0) = 1
aLstSrc(1) = 2
aLstSrc(2) = 3

ListBox1.DataSource = aLstSrc
```

You should initiate the array and populate within `For Each` loop in you example.

You can either create the array as String or Integer, but if you are required to perform further processing of the data Integer should be the best option.

Also refer this to get some more info on processing text file into arrays/ list: [VB.NET - Reading a text file containing tab-separated integers/doubles and storing them in arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052508/vb-net-reading-a-text-file-containing-tab-separated-integers-doubles-and-stori?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this out:

```
    Dim values As New List(Of Integer)

    Dim File_1 As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "SomeFile.Txt")
    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadLines(File_1)
        Dim m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(line, "\d+")
        If m.Success Then
            values.Add(Convert.ToInt32(m.Value))
        End If
    Next

    values.Sort()
    values.Reverse()
    ListBox3.DataSource = values
```

Comment: If your file is not going to change its format then something as simple as split function should work. You could split the lines and store in onto an array, retrieve the second index by after an isnumeric method. If I were you I'd enclose all these in a try catch block.